# Confusion of importing CSV file

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, import

I followed [this instruction](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) to import CSV file to my project. 
However, I found something that made me confused. I downloaded the demo project [here](https://github.com/railscasts/396-importing-csv-and-excel/tree/master/store-with-validations)

and in this project I did not know exactly how it added data to table(because I did not see any explain about code). The code here:

```
 <%= form_for @product_import do |f| %>
  <% if @product_import.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product_import.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this import from completing:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @product_import.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons"><%= f.submit "Import" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should take a closer look at the import method:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!
  end
end
```

The first line does exactly what it says, it opens the file you just uploaded. The first row in your spreadsheet should always contain headers. Therefore line 2 saves the first row as header.

Next you will loop trough all other rows until the last filled row. This is all the data in your CSV or Excel file. What happens in the row variable is that you create a custom hash where you couple the values of each row with the headers of the very first row.

Now to the real question. After creating your custom hash, you can find the products in your database by the id of your row hash. If no product is found a new one will be created. Next you slice all attributes off the custom hash which are accessible within your products model.

If all is well your product will be saved, otherwise an exception is raised.

Comment: I added it to controller file and it did not run correctly. In controller file, I put the content of import method into self.import(file) and it did nothing...

Comment: It should be in your model. You should follow the railscast step by step and you will be allright. My answer just explains how the import method works, which was what you asked.

Comment: yes, your explanation is clear. It seem that I may reconsider to my code and make it work correctly. thank you.

Comment: I think you should always follow a railscast instead of cloning the git. This way you will have more understanding about what the code does. Anyway, if your question is answered please (upvote and) accept my answer.